# Visual Studio says it can't find source code for a web-debug

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using VS2005, and have been for many years without problems, and 2003 before that.

Today suddenly, when I try and debug javascript on a site from the web, the debugger loads as normal but complains it can't find the source and offers me the chance to go looking for it. In the Script Explorer it shows all of the files loaded by the page, it just won't show me the source for them when I double-click on them.

I've tried resetting all settings to web-development default. Didn't work. I even tried exporting the settings from another machine (XP) I have with VS2005 on it that works fine. After importing to the faulty machine (on Win 7) it made no difference.

Any ideas?

Steps to recreate:
1. Open IE9, go to yahoo.com
2. Click View->External Script Debugger->Open
3. Once in the debugger it says cannot find source and offers me a dialog to help me find it on my local machine (why would it be there?).
4. In the Script Explorer I see all html and js files the page loaded, but upon double-clicking them, nothing happens. Usually it opens the source and you can set breakpoints.

Working config is on XP/IE8
Non-working config is on Win 7/IE9 *but was working fine before today*.

I just noticed a bizarre side-effect. The File menu in IE9 is greyed out during the debug session and even after I've closed VS. So freaky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no solution was found as to why VS2005 suddenly developed a lack of understanding as to how to get JavaScript source code for live sites. I uninstalled it and installed VS2010 instead and that's working just fine, on the same sites. Maybe re-installing VS2005 would have worked, but I'd had VS2010 around waiting to be installed for a while anyway, so two birds, one stone and all that.

It remains a mystery. No point anyone offering any further input now. The problem is history.